# Django Admin: How do I serialize data and store it in a model so that it can be restored by the user?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-admin

So what I have so far is a model called `Registration` and a model called `Deleted Registration`. I overrode the `deleted_selected` admin action for `Registration` so that instead of deleting the query, it would make `Deleted Registration`s. The thing is, it only saves the *most important parts*. Registrations have a few foreign keys and one-to-one fields.  Apparently just saving the most important data isn't good enough and we want to serialize all the data in the selected registration models and store it **with** the deleted registration. This way, when you select a few deleted registrations, you can click on `Restore deleted registrations`

I'll reiterate what I want so it's a little but more clear: I want to be able to "delete" registrations, where a new deleted registration is created. This way, they can view deleted registrations and, if need be, restore them.

Here is the registration model:

```py
class Registration(models.Model):

    objects = RegistrationManager()

    # Used to identify this object securely in urls without giving the actual primary key
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    sibs_event = models.ForeignKey("EventInstance", null=True, blank=True)

    date_registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # sibs event for this registration
    sibs_weekend = models.ForeignKey(SibsWeekend, null=False)

    payment_delegation = models.OneToOneField("PaymentDelegation", null=True, blank=True, related_name="registration", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Here is the deleted registration model:

```py
class DeletedRegistration(models.Model):
    """
    Just in case of bugs with purging registrants, store
    important registrant information in this model.
    """
    registrant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    registrant_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    registrant_phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, blank=True)
    delegate_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    delegate_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    num_of_participants = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, default=1)
    special_event = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

Here is the overridden delete_selected for registrations:

```py
def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        """
        This overrides the defult deleted_selected because we want to gather the data from the registration and create a
        DeletedRegistration object before we delete it.
        """
        for registration in queryset:
            reg = registration.get_registrant()

            if registration.payment_delegation:
                delegate_name = registration.payment_delegation.name
                delegate_email = registration.payment_delegation.email
            else:
                delegate_name = None
                delegate_email = None

            registration_to_delete = DeletedRegistration.objects.create(
                registrant_name = reg.full_name(),
                registrant_email = reg.email,
                registrant_phone_num = reg.phone,
                delegate_name = delegate_name,
                delegate_email = delegate_email,
                # Filtering out people (with True) who couldn't participate in events because we are only interested in the people
                # we had to reserve space and prepare materials for.
                num_of_participants = registration.get_num_party_members(True),
                special_event = registration.sibs_event,
            )
            registration.delete()
```

I appreciate your help! I just don't know what to do from here; I've been searching online for the ways I can do it but I cant wrap my mind around it. I want to save the serialized registration data as a **field** in deleted registration so that way I can have an admin action take that field and create a new registration from it.

Comment: Why not create a new field `is_deleted` on your Registration model? Anyway, if you need to serialize a model check out Django REST framework serializers. You can create a TextField to store the serialized data then you can deserialize it.

Comment: @Nad TextField then? I thought about having a field like that, but I wasn't sure how the user would view it unless they filtered the results, I wanted a totally new view, like in your email you have a deleted folder

Comment: In this case adding an is_deleted field on the Registration model is the way to go. Your deleted folder would then be the same view but filtered on that new field.